# mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, linode

I've looked at the various solutions from other threads but can't possibly figure this out; and solutions I've found aren't applying here. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and spun up a server a few days ago. The server has been running fine until it didn't. After taking 15 miniutes to shutdown, I have now booted and MySQL won't start:

```
systemctl1 status mysql.service

mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-03-01 09:04:59 GMT; 18s ago
Process: 6969 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 6967 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 6969 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 6970 (mysql-systemd-s)
CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
       └─control
         ├─6970 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
         └─7080 sleep 1

sudo journalctl -xe

Mar 01 09:08:31 dwight systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

/var/log/mysql/error.log.1 is showing no errors today (the day MySQL crashed) but has been logging up until yesterday. /var/log/mysql/error.log is empty.

Please can anyone advise on how to diagnose?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo service mysql start
```